# subdifferentiable implies conjugate equality

Tags: convex-analysis, duality-theorems, conjugate-gradient

For function $f(x)=\max_i x_i, x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
We define the Fenchel conjugate as
$$
f^*(x^*) = \sup_x\Big\{ \langle x^*,x\rangle-f(x)\Big\}\,.
$$

The standard subdifferential for $f(x)$ as
$$
\partial f(x)=\Big\{x^*\in E: \forall y\in E\quad f(y)\geq f(x)+\langle x^*,y-x\rangle\Big\}\quad \text{if } x\in \operatorname{dom}(f)\,.
$$
In the lecture note, it says

$$
x^*\in \partial f(x) \iff f^*(x^*)+f(x)=\langle x^*,x\rangle
$$
I am confused with this statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is simpler than you think and holds for general $f$.

When
$$\tag{1}
f^*(x^*)+f(x)=\langle x^*,x\rangle
$$ then this is an $x$ in the domain of $f$ that attains the supremum in
$$\tag{2}
f^*(x^*) = \sup_{x}\Big\{\langle x^*,x\rangle-f(x)\Big\}\,
$$
(without the braces this expression does not make sense).

Let $y\in E\,.$ Then it follows that
$$\tag{3}
\langle x^*,x\rangle-f(x)\ge\langle x^*,y\rangle-f(y)\,, 
$$
or
$$\tag{4}
f(y)\ge f(x)+\langle x^*,y-x\rangle\,.
$$
That is, $x^*\in\partial f(x)\,.$ Conversely, assume $x^*\in\partial f(x)\,.$ Then (4) and (3) hold for all $y\in E\,.$ But this means  $x$ is the one where $f$ attains the supremum in (2). Therefore (1) holds.